# How can I change all the Wazuh-Kibana-App logos my own?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, wazuh

I want to change all logos from Wazuh GUI that include all Kibana and Wazuh and Elastic-search logos and text's that includes there names.

Answer (score 0):

In order to  changue the Logos and images on the Wazuh GUI, you would need to go through the steps to set up and compile a custom version.

You can do that by downloading the Wazuh [Kibana App Repo](https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh-kibana-app). The you can look for the images and the text references on the files and change them manually.

The images for the logos, are located in the `public/assets` folder. You can check each image and replace it for the one you want to use in it's place.

Replacing the text is a bit more work, since, you would need to go through the html files, located on the `/public/` subfolders (templates, components).

After doing all the changes, you cand build the app and install it and use it.